# Why can't we search on comments?

Tags: support, comments, search

I know that we are not able to search in comments, but why? Is this a technical problem? Is this only a lack of funcionality of the software?

Comment: I'm puzzled. You can search for comments. They are part of the webpage, pure text. So you can search for them.

Comment: @John - correct, but only the ones deemed "most important"... the rest are hidden under AJAX.

Comment: @Isaac Waller: Use Google! It's much better than anything Jeff can invent. Do we really need a Ninja search option for comments?

Comment: @John Smithers: That's what Isaac is saying--you can't use Google reliably because it will only index the top-voted comments in long threads.  Google doesn't index ajax-fetched content.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23771

Answer (score 3):

> Is this a technical problem? Is this only a lack of funcionality of the software?

More of a philosophical problem. I think Jeff has said somewhere that comments aren't considered *content* per se, and that they shouldn't be considered part of the permanent, canonical question/answer.  As such, he probably doesn't think there's much value in searching them (if there's anything important there, it should be in the question or answer!).

Comment: In this answer (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23771#23786), Jeff suggests that he'd like to be able to search comments, but doesn't give any indication that it's ever going to happen.

Answer (score 0):

It's a feature that has not been enabled in (or even written into) the software.

Comment: I'd vote for the feature to be written in and offered as an advanced search option. I commented under http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23771/166799