# Is it possible to search for questions without comments?

Tags: feature-request, comments, questions, search

So when browsing questions to answer I search:

> answers:0 [WhateverTagHere]

But sometimes these answers are already answered because some people commented on them. Is there a way to filter the comments? Anyone else feel it would be a nice feature if they don't have it already?

Note: I already tried `comments:0` and that didn't work.

Comment: This is a Feature Request, built upon: "[Why can't we search on comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/31238/282094)".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, use `answers:0 [whatevertag]` for searching..

I think a filter on comments is useless because most questions are not answered in comments. If they are answered in comments then you are perfectly allowed to post a real answer of what the answer in comments was. (I would recommend this so to be excluded from future searches as well)

Comment: yes, this is like a free reputation machine and a totally legitimate use of the system. "answers" posted as comments are fair game to be reposted as real answers.

Comment: @Jeff: I had wondered about using comments that provide answers. There have been times when I would have an answer, but comments provided more in depth details that I would not necessarily have thought of.

Comment: @dboarman it is fair game for future answers to incorporate feedback from earlier comments

Comment: @Jeff, it's fair. But not everyone reads Meta discussions saying it's fair ;)