# Comments from deleted users are confusing

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, deleted-accounts

When a user leaves a comment, then later deletes their account, their name on the comments shows up as "Deleted". I think this is a little misleading, because it makes it look like the comment has been deleted but somehow I still see it, particularly because of the juxtaposition of the timestamp. I'd suggest changing it to "deleted user" or something like that. Or maybe remove the name and only show the timestamp.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't true anymore (hasn't been for some time).  When a user's being deleted the *very* first thing we do is set their username to "user", e.g. "user123456", that's what'll be shown on any comments/posts that they owned after deletion is complete.

Here's a few of the most recent examples.

- [get current URL and previous URL when user pushes button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466064/get-current-url-and-previous-url-when-user-pushes-button)
- [NSTAbleView is not displaying contents of the NSMutableArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431289/nstableview-is-not-displaying-contents-of-the-nsmutablearray)
- [How I can convert string[] to list<int>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465704/how-i-can-convert-string-to-listint)

(*special case note*: the user name when the owner doesn't exist *may* be different than user123456, since in the migrations case we carry the name over, though the user may not exist on the destination site)

Comment: Is it possible to clean up the old ones then? here's where i saw it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31236/why-cant-we-search-on-comments/

Comment: @Kip - Unfortunately no, not unless there's something generic we'd want to put everywhere (like Anonymous, which isn't really correct either)...given the user is long gone and the FK pointing to them is null, there's no data to generate the "user123456" in the system.