# Search term "XYURLGenerator" yields no results

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, search

[image]I am trying to search for `XYURLGenerator`, which exists in the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771309/jfreechart-scatter-plot-click-to-popup-information/15775096?noredirect=1#comment22460747_15775096).

Why won't StackOverflow find these questions?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not so sure the comments are indexed in the search. Actually I'm pretty sure they aren't, because comments are meant to be volatile. They can be removed or added as the user who wrote it want. Answers/Questions can not be removed as easily.

Comment: *Comments are second-class citzens at best*. It is all about questions and answers here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comments are not indexed in the search. Comments are ephermal, and are prone to deletion at any time -- they only need to be used for suggesting clarifications to the post. No real need to make them searchable.

Generally, you may use [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=XYURLGenerator%20site:stackoverflow.com) to find these, though that comment is too new to have been indexed. It probably will be by tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23771/how-can-i-search-stackoverflow-comments), you can't search comments directly. This still applies today.

Hugo Dozois is correct, comments are not indexed in the search. This is because they are not intended to be permanent, and should only be used for minor clarifications.