# View a user's list of comments sorted by score?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-voting

On a user page it's easy to view a list of that user's questions and answers sorted by score. You can also see a list of a user's comments sorted by date under "activity, comments". I was curious to see what my high score comments were, but there doesn't seem to be a way to view this.

Is there a way to view a user's comments sorted by score?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Here's a data explorer query which lists a user's comments in descending order of score:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/109328/my-highest-rated-comments

---

It has the post-link, comment score, and comment body.

Comment: Ahhh a low-effort way to not only view my comments and their scores, but also to actually go to the posts containing the comments and see what I was talking about. Thanks :)

Comment: @Douglas: When using the Data Explorer you should keep in mind that the data dump is updated weekly, not instantly.

Answer (score 9):

You can view your highest voted comments with that link

```
 https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/1655144/comments?order=desc&min=5&sort=votes&site=stackoverflow
```

It displays only comments with at least 5 votes (`min=5`).
 `1655144` is your Stack Overflow user id.

Answer (score 2):

You can by running this query on Data Stack Exchange [HERE](https://data.stackexchange.com/role-playing%20gamesmeta/query/947/my-comment-score-distribution). Just enter your user ID.

Your user ID is 1655144 for StackOverflow.

Comment: This displays the distribution, but doesn't tell you which comments they are. (This is also helpful.)