# Sort comments on my profile by votes

Tags: discussion, comments, profile-page, up-votes, sorting

I would like to sort my comments by votes.  My hope is to find my old obsolete comments and delete them when they don't add value to the posts.  I assume that if they have an up vote at all, they are valuable.  It may also be useful to get feedback on which comments are helpful to others.

Related: [search by keyword](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148066/can-i-search-my-comments-using-some-keywords), [search comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23771/how-can-i-search-stackoverflow-comments), etc.

Comment: There's probably a query on data.SE, I think I remember using one that did just this

Comment: I find that a lot of obsolete comments have a lot of upvotes.  It's common enough to, for example, point out a problem in a post, get upvotes for a correct analysis, and then have the author fix the post.  Such a comment is no both upvoted and obsolete.

Comment: [data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Sorry, I missed that. This is a duplicate.  Interestingly, the answers allow a CSV download which you can search.

Comment: No need to be sorry; I often find that the best way to determine if a question has already been asked is to ask it (again) and wait for the close votes. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/30334/my-comments) on data.SE.

Note that as @Servy mentions in the comments, high voted comments can be obsolete as well, so don't forget to look through those too.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, I linked the wrong query. Edited

Comment: Thank-you.  This works; you need your *numeric ID* from your **Stack Overflow** home page as a parameter.

Comment: @art Yes, correct.